# Hadoop: There is no file in HDFS path

Tags: java, linux, hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs

I setup the HDFS for Hadoop v.1.2.1 correctly and the `hadoop fs -ls /user/${username}` returns the files in the HDFS correctly. But when I want to run the following command I face a problem:

```
username=$USER
hadoop fs -mkdir /user/${username}/project
hadoop fs -put ${inputfilespath}*  /user/${username}/project/
mpJar=${rootPath}mp/src/mp.jar
mp_exec=mp
MR_HADOOPJAR=/opt/hadoop-1.2.1/hadoop-core-1.2.1.jar
MR_MANIFEST=${rootPath}mp/src/manifest.txt
echo "Compiling mp source code.."
javac -classpath $MR_HADOOPJAR ${rootPath}mp/src/*.java
echo "Creating mp jar.."
jar cvfm $mpJar $MR_MANIFEST ${rootPath}mp/src/*.class
export HADOOP_CLASSPATH=$mpJar
hadoop $mp_exec hdfs:/user/${username}/project
```

This is the error:

```
Usage: <input directory>
There is no files in this path: /user/mohebbi/project
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at mp.main(mp.java:24)
```

But when I use the `hadoop fs -ls /user/mohebbi/project` it shows that the files are in this directory. (`mohebbi` is the username). I am confused and please help me.

Also, I tried `hadoop $mp_exec hdfs://localhost:9000/user/${username}/project` and I faced the same error.

THanks

Comment: I think you are confusing `/home/${username}/project` with `/user/${username}/project`

Comment: And you setup Hadoop v1.2.1 when 2.7.2 is the latest?

Comment: Additionally, you are getting a NullPointerException, so it looks like you aren't handling your errors correctly in `mp.java`

Comment: Thank you cricket_007 that was a mistake on my post. I update my post. I need version 1.2.1 because I want to run an old code. Also, I am getting null pointer exception because the code can not find the path. How can I pass the hdfs path correctly to the java file?

Comment: Are you able to run the wordcount mapreduce examples on the Apache Hadoop site?

Comment: why have you pasted the code for some script when your java code is creating an issue. Paste java code

Comment: @PreetiKhurana I posted my java code here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39359412/hadoop-can-not-find-the-mapper-class